Decidability of Skolem arithmetic via the Feferman-Vaught Theorem
In the Wikipedia article about Skolem arithmetic, it is claimed that one can use the Feferman-Vaught Theorem to prove that Skolem arithmetic is decidable. However, I can't follow the proof in the article. The proof runs roughly as follows:
Let $L$ be the first-order language with $=$ and one binary function symbol $\cdot$. Skolem arithmetic is the theory of the $L$-structure $(\mathbb{N},=,\cdot)$ consisting of the natural numbers with multiplication.
Let $\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$ be the $L$-structure consisting of all sequences of natural numbers, with $\cdot$ given by pointwise addition, and let $\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}_*$ be the $L$-structure consisting of all sequences of natural numbers with only finitely many non-zero entries with $\cdot$ given by pointwise addition.
First, it follows from the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic that $(\mathbb{N},=,\cdot)$ is isomorphic to the $\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}_*$. Next, one can use the Feferman-Vaught Theorem to see that the decidability of $\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$ reduces to the decidability of Presburger arithmetic (that is, to the theory of $(\mathbb{N},=,+)$). Presburger arithmetic is known to be decidable. QED
I have two questions:

Why does the decidability of $\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$ imply the decidability of $\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}_*$?
How, exactly, does the decidability of $\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$ reduce to the decidability of Presburger arithmetic via the Feferman-Vaught Theorem?

I will expand a bit on my second question. I am familiar with the version of the Feferman-Vaught Theorem that is stated in Model Theory by Chang and Keisler (Proposition 6.3.2). There, the theorem says that every $L$-formula $\phi$ is determined by a sequence $(\sigma;\psi_1,\ldots,\psi_m)$ where $\sigma$ is a formula in the language $L_\text{BA}$ of Boolean algebras and $\psi_i$ for $1\leq i\leq m$ are $L$-formulas. It seems to me that in order to use this theorem together with the decidability of Presburger arithmetic to prove that Skolem arithmetic is decidable, one would have to do two things:

Express $(\mathbb{N},=,\cdot)$ as a reduced power $\prod_D \mathbb{N}$ of $(\mathbb{N},=,+)$, where $D$ is a filter on some index set $I$;
Prove that the theory of the $L_\text{BA}$-structure $\mathcal{P}(I)/D$ is decidable.

But I don't see how to manage this based on the information in the Wikipedia article on Skolem arithmetic. Does anyone know how this is supposed to be done? I am a bit lost.

The "Feferman-Vaught theorem" is really a family of very similar theorems that apply to a wide variety of "product" constructions that produce an $L$-structure from a family of $L$-structures. These include direct products, reduced products, Boolean products, generalized products, weak generalized products, etc.
Chang and Keisler state the Feferman-Vaught theorem for the case of reduced products, and you're right that $\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}_*$ is not a reduced power of $\mathbb{N}$. But if you look at the original paper (The first order properties of products of algebraic systems, 1959) by Feferman and Vaught, you'll find that they actually prove their theorem (Theorems 3.1 and 3.2) in the generality of a construction they called the "relativized generalized product". This construction is flexible enough to encompass a wide variety of interesting examples, as described in Section 4. In particular, the "weak direct power" (Section 4.2) is an example of a relativized generalized product. And your structure $\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}_*$ is a weak direct power of $\mathbb{N}$. It follows (by the general Feferman-Vaught theorem restricted to the special case of weak direct powers) that decidability of the theory of $\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}_*$ reduces to decidability of Presburger Arithmetic.
The analysis of weak direct powers is actually due to Mostowski ("On Direct Products of Theories", 1952), and Feferman and Vaught indicate that their work is a generalization of Mostowski's. Bés gives a nice explanation of Mostowski's work and its application to decidability of Skolem Arithmetic in his paper (An Application of the Feferman-Vaught Theorem to Automata and Logics for Words over an Infinite Alphabet, 2008, pages 10-11).

Thank you for the excellent answer! This explains why I was so confused
